# how to show empty as null in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a table in postgresql where initially the table will be empty **not as null value it will be empty**

i am running a select query which will display the value as empty, but i need it to return null

this is my query

```
select job_status,refreshed_properties,total_number_of_properties_to_be_refreshed 
from job_table
```

this is my python code

```
 check_job_status  = """select job_status,refreshed_properties,total_number_of_properties_to_be_refreshed 
                        from job_table"""
cursor.execute(check_job_status)
job_status = cursor.fetchall()
print (job_status)
print("the above result is the job status ")
```

either i need to handle it in postgresql or need to handle in python

table structure

[image]

python output

[image]

Comment: So you want to select from an empty table? You cannot. (well: you can, but it results in zero retrieved rows)  You can **detect** that the table (or the result set)  is empty, and if so: perform some action in the python frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Use `nulliff()`:

```
select 
    nullif(job_status, '') as status,  
    refreshed_properties, 
    total_number_of_properties_to_be_refreshed 
from job_table
```

If `job_status` is equal to the empty string, this returns a `null` value instead.

Comment: it still returns empty sir!

Answer (score 0):

> i am running a select query which will display the value as empty, but i need it to return null

I think you want to return None and not null. Isnt it?

Just check if the list is empty and print `None` if it is.

```
job_status = cursor.fetchall()
print (job_status if len(job_status) else None)
print("the above result is the job status ")
```